# C++: Segfault on accessing abstract superclass' enum

Tags: c++, inheritance, enums

I'm sure I'm missing something fairly simple here, but I'm getting a segmentation fault when I try to access an enum stored in a superclass.

I'm building a very simple chess game. I have a class called Piece, which the different pieces (pawn, knight, etc.) inherit. The class declaration in the header file "ChessPieces.hpp" looks like this:

```
enum Colour { BLACK, WHITE };

class Piece { //Parent superclass, never instantiated.
    protected:
        Colour colour;
    public:
        Piece(Colour colour);
        ~Piece();
        virtual bool legalMove (pair<int, int> fromP, pair<int, int> toP) = 0;
        virtual void print ();
        Colour getColour ();
};
```

While the related methods in the "ChessPieces.cpp" file look like this:

```
Piece::Piece (Colour c) {
    colour = c;
}

Piece::~Piece () { }

void Piece::print () {
    switch (colour) {
        case BLACK:
            cout << "Black"; break;
        case WHITE:
            cout << "White"; break;
    }
}

Colour Piece::getColour () {
    return colour;
}
```

This compiles, links etc. just fine. However, when the getColour() method is called on an instance of one of the Piece subclasses, a segmentation fault occurs. Why is this?

UPDATE:

Here's where the code is called. The Pieces reside in a `map<pair<int, int>, Piece>`.

```
//Check if square is on board.
if (!isRealSquare(fromP) || !isRealSquare(fromP)) {
    cout << "Sorry, one of your squares isn't on the board!\n";
    return;
}
//Check piece exists.
if ((*pieces)[fromP] != NULL) {
    cout << "There is no piece there.\n";
    return;
}
//Check player is moving one of their own pieces
if ((*pieces)[fromP] -> getColour() != playerTurn) {
    cout << "That's not one of your pieces.\n";
    return;
}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: can you show us where you call it?

Comment: Show some (minimal) code that reproduces the problem or it didn't happen.

Comment: Apologies, have amended. Virtualising the deconstructor doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: How do you asure that `fromP` exists in `pieces` map?

Comment: I check before - will amend again!

Comment: That could be the problem. if `fromP` doesn't exsit in pieces. `(*pieces)[fromP] != NULL` will insert a record into `pieces` and return true. AND the value of this element is null.

Comment: So does `Piece` have a meaningful comparison with `NULL`, and an `operator->`??

Comment: @JoelAuterson Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40164/should-we-close-fix-my-program-questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at your checks carefully, you will see that you can only reach this:

```
if ((*pieces)[fromP] -> getColour() != playerTurn)
```

when `(*pieces)[fromP]` is `NULL`. So, you are de-referencing a NULL pointer.